# How to sort a multidimensional array in jquery by one field?

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have this array in jquery:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[1] = new Array();
myArray[2] = new Array();
myArray[3] = new Array();
myArray[4] = new Array();
myArray[5] = new Array();
```

The element `myArray[x][1]` (x can be 1 to 5) contains a numeric value (a price) and the element `myArray[x][2]` another numeric value (an identifier). I need to order the array by the value of `myArray[x][1]` (the price) without separating every price from his identifier (his `[x][2]`).

How do i?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects?rq=1

Comment: @Alex, That isn't the same thing

Comment: @musefan: It's *very nearly* the same thing, as arrays are objects. But probably not an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I wouldn't think it wise to try and access object properties by using an index, but I suppose the answers are relevant (assuming the OP can see the similarities between the different code examples)

Comment: @musefan: It **is** slightly advanced, no question. Note that with standard JavaScript arrays, "indexes" are actually property names, because standard JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, of course. But if we call everything what it really is in javascript then we don't have many words to describe anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Array#sort` for that:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

...assuming that the `[1]` entries in the sub-arrays are in fact numbers.

See live example below.

---

Side note #1: Note that array indexes start at `0`, so your array as quoted has `undefined` (rather than a sub-array) in the first position. You'll want to fix that before doing the above, possibly by doing the below.

---

Side note #2: In JavaScript, there is almost never any reason to write `new Array()`. Instead, just use an array literal: `[]`. Your quoted code, for instance, could be:

```
var myArray = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
];
```

...assuming you fix the error identified above.

---

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uwIXasa/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uwIXasa/1/edit):

```
// [0] is the id, [1] is the price
var myArray = [
    [1, 14.95],
    [2, 7.50],
    [3, 8.99],
    [4, 12.25],
    [5, 13.72]
];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

var index, entry;
for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index) {
    entry = myArray[index];
    console.log(index + ": " + entry[0] + " - " + entry[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
0: 2 - 7.5
1: 3 - 8.99
2: 4 - 12.25
3: 5 - 13.72
4: 1 - 14.95
```

Comment: work perfectly, you saved the day! ^^ I admit i've not understood completely what's going on, but i will take my time to do it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Elisabetta: The `Array#sort` function accepts a function that it will call repeatedly to compare entries from the array while sorting it. It passes the function two args (the entries to compare). The function should return a negative value if the first should "before" the second, `0` if the two entries are equivalent, or a positive number if the second should be "before" the first. So if you're comparing by price, and if price is the second entry (`[1]`) in each sub-array, then `a[1] - b[1]` is negative if `a[1]` is `<` `b[1]`, `0` if they're the same, or positive if `b[1]` is `>` `a[1]`.

Comment: cool, i got the point! Thank you very much. I was able to get all to work perfectly. ^^

Comment: I think StackOverflow should implement  "Thank you so much" button for an answer like this :).

Comment: @Zlatko - I think that's the Upvote button. :-) (But you need more rep first.)

Comment: @Zlatko - LOL, my bad, I thought you needed more rep. But [the site tells me otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder All I needed is an idea. More tools in my toolbelt. Thank you for that. I am not chasing rep although I am a long time member. Nice to hear from you btw. It is good that you are so active.