# sort an array without column name

Tags: jquery, arrays, highcharts

I am plotting HighChart Graph .I have data in  2DArray .It contains data as x and y coordinates as

```
          [0.1.1 , 4.8]
          [0.2.1 ,  5.71]
          [1.1.4 ,  5.79]
          [0.4.3.0 , null]
```

First column data has to be with 2 decibels ..I cant change 0.1.1 to 0.1

I dont have column Name in Array .I want to sort this array By first Column

I have tried in JSBin

http://jsbin.com/uwIXasa/40/edit

this is not working too 
I have tried this :

```
 TestArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            var a1 = a[1], b1 = b[1];
            if (a1 == b1) return 0;
            return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
        });
```

this is not sorting

I have read similar post ..but many are suggested to solve by column Name

.Please Suggest

Comment: sorry sir ..I have Edited the Code

Comment: Numbers seems to be wrong : 0.1406.0 -> 0.1406 ?

Comment: can you write out your variable a little better? what sort of variable is 0.1406.0? is GraphData an array of arrays? why are they all separated like that?

Comment: The declaration of `GraphData` would result in a fatal error written like this.

Comment: Sir , i Edited my Code ..My Array is not declared right this ..I just took the data at runtime..I was just looking if there is a way to sort  data with 2 decibels

Comment: None of this is valid javascript, numbers can only have one period, you're setting a variable to multiple arrays or something strange etc ?

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978140/how-to-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-jquery-by-one-field

Comment: this is not working sir ..myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
}); ...not sorting ..I even try My Code in in JSBIn ..this is link http://jsbin.com/uwIXasa/40/edit ..

Comment: Numbers in Javascript can't be like this, like @adeneo said it's not valid. Why not using Strings and compare them ? (but this still won't work with Highcharts, at least not directly)

Comment: Indeed, Highcharts won't display strings as values, however, you can use them as categories. But this: `0.4.3.0` is not proper Javascript number. It will throw an error, so you can't sort that array.